# Google bot is not able to trigger personalization rule?

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, presentation, personalization, robots.txt

The task is to determine if there is a possible solution to allow Sitecore editors to apply date-based and traffic-eligibility-based rules to content items which are visible to Bots such as Googlebot.

I have created custom rule as well but this rule is also not triggering by google bot. Google bot only able to show the default personalized rule even I have tried to apply simple date based rule and day based rule still the same issue.
[image]

please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add rules you have tried. There is default Sitecore condition rule to check if device is bot. Do you have Visitor Identification added  to your layout?

Comment: How are you testing that googlebot is not seeing the rule applied?

Comment: Do you have a WAF in place or anything at the network level that could be interfering with this at all? Which version of SC are you running? What does your infrastructure look like?

Comment: @KamilC Yes I have also checked with default Sitecore condition device is bot as well the still the same issue. And the Visitor Identification is also added in layout.

Comment: @MarcelGruber The Sitecore version is 9.3, I will update you with WAF and infrastructure info shortly.

Comment: @DeanOBrien for testing google bot I am switching the user-agent from DevTools Network tab and using the Googlebot user agent. I also tried with user-agent-switcher extension. The personalization rule works if I am trying to load website without changing the user-agent first time and after all cookies and cache saved then if I am switching the user-agent to Googlebot then it is working fine. But after clearing all cookies and cache if I am switching the user-agent to Googlebot first then loading website and then it is not working which is the right approach to test Googlebot.

Comment: Have you tried a private/anonymous browser tab or an entirely different browser, in which you are not logged into Sitecore? Whenever you are testing anything related to analytics, separation of sessions and logins are crucial.

Comment: As Marcel mentioned, clear your cookies and cache and or try incognito mode. Do you have Device Detection enabled? As far as i remember built in rule for IsBot is using it. Any errors in logs?